# What does this function do in Visual Foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

What does the getcolor() function do? It returns some random number for me. Even does the color change with this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the (Visual Foxpro 9) help file:

> Displays the Windows Color dialog box and returns the color number of
>   the chosen color.   GETCOLOR([nDefaultColorNumber])
>
> Parameters nDefaultColorNumber
>
> Specifies the color that is initially selected when the Color dialog
>   box is displayed. If nDefaultColorNumber doesn't correspond to a color
>   in the Color dialog box, the first color in the Color dialog box is
>   selected. If you omit nDefaultColorNumber, black is selected.